# Can the hamiltonian be derived from phase space evolution?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space

Given the phase space evolution of  a system, $x(t)$ and $p(t)$, is there any way of getting the hamiltonian to make a later study of the system under the hamiltonian formalism?

My first thought was to take the time derivatives of the phase space coordinates, $\dot{x}(t)$ and $\dot{p}(t)$, and then try to integrate the Hamilton's equations
$$
\dot{x} = \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p} \quad\text{and}\quad \dot{p} =- \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial x}\ ,
$$
which gives me a hamiltonian with the generic form
$$
H(x,p,t) = f(x,p,t) + g(t)\ ,
$$
where $f$ is the result of direct integration of the phase space space coordinates and $g$ is an arbitrary function of time.

However I think that this is not a correct approach, since I think that I should get rid of the time dependence of $x$ and $p$ prior to integrating the Hamilton's equations.

How would you get a hamiltonian when the trajectories $x(t)$ and $p(t)$ are given without any extra information?

Comment: Do you know the trajectories for every possible choice of initial condition, or do you only know a single trajectory?

Comment: @J.Murray I have single expressions for x(t) and p(t) only, so I suppose that they represent a single trajectory where the initial conditions were already applied.

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer the question "if you know the equations $\dot{x}=\ldots~,\dot{p}=\ldots~$ how you get the Hamiltonian?"

To obtain the  Hamiltonian, you have to solve these partial differential equations :

$$-{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}H \left( x,p \right) =f \left( x
 \right)
$$
and

$${\frac {\partial }{\partial p}}H \left( x,p \right) =g \left( p
 \right)
$$

which give you the solution:

$$H \left( x,p \right) ={ F_2} \left( x \right) +{ F_1} \left( p
 \right)
$$

with :

$$f \left( x \right) =-{\frac {d}{dx}}{ F_2} \left( x \right)\tag 1$$
$$g \left( p \right) ={\frac {d}{dp}}{ F_1} \left( p \right)\tag 2$$

**Example:**

$$\dot{p}=-k\,x~,\dot{x}=\frac pm$$

$\Rightarrow$

Eq. (1)

$$-kx=-{\frac {d}{dx}}{F_2} \left( x \right) ~\Rightarrow~,F_2=\frac  12 k\,x^2+c_2$$

Eq. (2)

$$\frac pm=\frac{d}{dp}\,F_1~\Rightarrow~,F_1=\frac 12 \frac{p^2}{m}+c_1$$

and the Hamiltonian is:

$$H=\frac 12\left(k\,x^2+\frac {p^2}{m}\right)+c$$

**Edit**

in case that you know $x=x(t)~,p=p(t)$ you have to solve these equations

$$-{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}H \left( x,p \right) =f \left( t
 \right)
$$
and

$${\frac {\partial }{\partial p}}H \left( x,p \right) =g \left( t
 \right)
$$
($f(t)=\dot{x}~,g(t)=\dot{p}$)

which give you the solution:

$$H=F_3(t)\,x+F_4(t)\,p+F_5(t)$$

where :

$$f(t)=-F_3~,g(t)=F_4$$

Comment: I know what you say but, in my case what I have is the time evolution of x and p. I mean, the functions x(t) and p(t) that one usually get after solving the differential equations of movement. I don't have the relations x = x(p) and p = p(x).

Comment: I will write you the solution soon

Comment: @Jaime_mc2 see new document